# Obfuscating java class files with yGuard fails to resolve few external Jar files

Tags: java, tomcat7, yguard

I have a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. After building the java source code, I wanted to obfuscate the class files using `yGuard`. The external Jar files have been put in the `lib` folder in the Tomcat directory and the build path is configured according to that path. I included that path as a external classes in the `build.xml` ANT file.

In the shrink log, I get warnings like mentioned below. Thinking that these are warnings, I proceed ahead, and replace the old class files with the new ones.

But when starting the server, the Web Project it doesn't work properly. Meaning that I am not able to login, or use the project in any other way.

I have tried Proguard as well but the same warnings persists there as well. Tried with `-ignorewarnings` as well but the same problem persists when replaced the original class files.

The `build.xml` file:

```
<project name="project" default="yguard" basedir=".">
    <target depends="jar" name="yguard">
      <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask"
      classpath="libs/yguard.jar"/>
      <yguard>
        <inoutpair in="project.jar" out="project-obf.jar"/>

        <externalclasses>
          <pathelement location="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/lib/*.jar"/>
        </externalclasses>

        <shrink logfile="${shrinklog}">
        </shrink>
      </yguard>

    </target>

    <!-- compile -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
      <javac srcdir="${srcDir}" includes="com/technomedia/**/*.java"
        destdir="${classDir}">
      </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- create .jar -->
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
      <jar jarfile="project.jar"
        basedir="build/classes"
        includes="com/technomedia/**">
      </jar>
    </target>
  </project>
```

The Waning messages that I get in `shrink.xml` file:

```
<!-- no entrypoints given - using class access public and protected on all inoutpairs. -->
<!-- parsing D:\TMSS\Project\Proguard\src\Proguard\ProGuard.jar -->
<!-- WARNING:Unresolved external dependency: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not found! -->
<!-- WARNING:Unresolved external dependency: org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound not found! -->
<!-- WARNING:Unresolved external dependency: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not found! -->
<!-- WARNING:Unresolved external dependency: org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet not found! -->
<!-- WARNING:Unresolved external dependency: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not found! -->
<!-- WARNING:Unresolved external dependency: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not found! -->
```

I expect that after replacing the class files in `build/classes` directory from `project-obf.jar`(after extracting) should work fine.